# Appcelerator Titanium: Cannot set TabGroup Nav Bar to hidden

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm trying to use the TabGroup in Titanium Alloy, but hide the tab group buttons at the bottom of the screen.

In their documentation there is a property called `navBarHidden`, which it says will hide the bar if it is set to true. But it doesn't work.

```
<Window>
    <TabGroup id="mainTabGroup" navBarHidden="true" class="container">
        <Tab id="tab1" title="Tab 1">
            <Window id="win1" title="Tab 1">
               <Label id="label1" color="#999">I am Window 1</Label>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
        <Tab id="tab2" title="Tab 2">
            <Window id="win2" title="Tab 2">
                <Label id="label2" color="#999">I am Window 2</Label>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
        <!-- Use the Require tag to include external Ti.UI.Tab views -->
    </TabGroup>
</Window>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: you are programming to android or ios ?

Comment: ideally for both, if that's possible?

Comment: navBarHidden is just for android

Comment: anyway try with yourWindow.hideNavBar(); preferably in an event listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem. I need to put a Window inside a tab element and then add the `tabBarHidden` property. So my view XML file looks like similar to this:

```
<TabGroup id="mainTabGroup">

    <Tab>
        <Window id="mainWindow" title="The Title" tabBarHidden="true">

        </Window>
    </Tab>

</TabGroup>
```

And in my controller:

```
$.mainTabGroup.open();
```